# Rust free concrete fasteners

Tags: concrete, bolts, fastener, rust

I need to fasten a 3/4 inch PVC trim board to a poured concrete basement wall.  Since this will be on the exterior of the house I want to avoid rusting of the fastener.  The previous pressure treated board fell off when the concrete nails rusted and broke off.  I was considering using Tapcon screws and counter sinking the heads and filling with a paintable epoxy.  I know the Tapcons will rust at some point. Does anyone know of a stainless steel concrete fastener?

Comment: Most coated fasteners should last a lot than common non coated fasteners.  Tapcons are coated, but could get galvanize or other coatings.  Most will last much longer than non coated fastenings.

Comment: You should just drill and insert anchors, into which you would drive stainless-steel screws.

Answer (score 3):

Tapcons and similar are available in stainless:

https://www.tapcon.com/products/concrete-screw-anchors/410-stainless-steel-tapcon

Answer (score 2):

You have various options.  The thickness of the fastener matters.  Really a hot dipped galvanized fastener of sufficient thickness should last decades.  Are you close to a marine environment? - that will speed oxidation of fasteners.

If you want the fastener to never rust out you could go with stainless steel and epoxy.  Something like HY-150 or there is a simpson strong tie version.  A lot of structural components are drilled and epoxied into concrete so certainly this will work to hold up a simple panel.

I have some pvc panels that I plan to install on concrete - I'll probably just use the strongest PL - PL Premium.  Seems like PVC is listed as compatible.

Comment: PL is construction adhesive?  It's not a marine environment, just exposed to snow and rain.  I tried a construction adhesive but it did not hold well on pressure treated and concrete.  What is HY-50?

Comment: Yeah PL is construction adhesive - the materials have to be dirt / dust free.  Is the PVC panel touching the ground or free hanging?  HY-150 is a two part epoxy made by Hilti. 
 https://www.loctiteproducts.com/en/products/build/construction-adhesives/loctite_pl_premiumpolyurethaneconstructionadhesive.html

Comment: @Genki PL Premium is polyurethane so it may act different than solvent-based construction adhesives. PL needs to cure under pressure or it doesn't stick well.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The panel will be under a walk out basement door aluminum threshhold.  The bottom of it is only a couple of inches off an asphalt surface but there is plenty of splash from roof runoff.  My plan now is to drill some 3/8" holes, fill them with epoxy and fasten the board with SS trim screws into this epoxy, when cured.  Back it all up with PL.